# Implement RSS feed in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So, I've been learning react native lately and I am trying to create an RSS reader.I have managed to Download the RSS data but I am stuck in implementing them into JSX ( Screen). I've been trying using setState method but it didn't work.
I can get the RSS data logged into Console but I can't display them in user through JSX

PS: Comments are just tests that I made

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    feed: {},
    items: {}
  };

  RSS() {
    return fetch("http://di.ionio.gr/feed/")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(responseData => rssParser.parse(responseData))
      .then(rss => {
        this.setState(() => ({
          //...prevState,
          feed: rss
          //titles: rss.items,
        }));
      });
  }

  render() {
    {this.RSS();}
    return (
      <View style={styles.top}>
        <HeaderScreen {...this.props} />
        <Text>{this.state.feed.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I've been using react-native-rss-parser.

I also tried without setState but that also didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup, you're creating an endless loop.  This is because you have a side effect (i.e. network request) in your render function.

When your request returns and you call `setState` your component is rendered again, which in turn calls the network again with `this.RSS()`, etc. etc. etc.

To fix this, move the `this.RSS()` to either your `constructor` function or better yet to the `componentDidMount` function.

i.e.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.RSS();
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.top}>
      <Text>{this.state.feed.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks . I fixed the endless loop  but I still can't display them through JSX. Its because rss.items is an array and I cant display an array in jsx like {this.state.items[0].title}

Comment: @MakisGrammenos in the code you provided, you didn't set items?  Anyhow, you can loop over items (using `.map`) to render a component for each item